# VBA to paste values when formula changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a excel forecasting workbook which is mainly formula driven and works fine. The only thing left to do is for the workbook to automatically paste special values when the cell reference changes and for the difference to automatically change to be this month – previous month.
First my table currently looks something  like this

```
        M1          M2          M3          M4      .... M12
Pay     100         100          100         100        100
Income -50          -50          -50         -50        -50
```

I have an IF function that formulates under the months which either returns “CURR” if current month, “LOCKED” if previous month and “0” if future months.

When the month changes automatically from =MONTH(TODAY()) I want the macro paste special values on  the above data where the IF = “LOCKED” so to track forecasting movement.
Secondly if its month 4 (for example) I want it to also calculate the difference between current and previous so to explain movement i.e 4-3. And also change month on month. This is on a different table.
I have searched the web for days and cannot find any solutions to this so any help would be greatful.

Comment: A formula evaluation can't trigger a `Worksheet_Change` event, unfortunately. And in any case, you certainly don't want to be firing this macro every time a cell changes, you just want to paste values once your entire table data has been updated, right? Why not just add a button to call a macro to do your pasteSpecial?